# find expected value of number of animals

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Assume that each person's (unique) favorite animal is independently and equally likely to be one of 23 possibilities. For a group of 81 people: What is the expected number of animals that are the favorite of exactly 7 people?
I got completely stuck at this weird question. I tried to calculate the probability that no animal is the favorite of 7 people, but this feels too complicated for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about indicator functions?

Comment: What is the probability that an **A**nteater is exactly seven people's favorite animal?  What is the probability that a **B**aboon is exactly seven people's favorite animal?  (*The calculation should be very similar to the first*).  Calculate those via binomial distribution.  Combine the results via linearity of expectation.

Comment: Related question, what is the probability that you flip exactly seven heads when flipping a coin $81$ times given that the coin is unfairly weighted as to land on heads with probability $\frac{1}{23}$ and tails with probability $\frac{22}{23}$

Comment: @JMoravitz could you elaborate? I am still confused.

Comment: @biden Do you or do you not understand the related question I posed about coins?  That is a routine textbook example of a question where you use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  Have you or have you not heard of the phrase "[linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties)"?

Comment: The punchline is that you can focus all of your attention solely on the first animal and do calculations about that animal alone, and use the results to describe the expectation for *all* animals.  We do *not* care to find the actual distribution of our random variable.  It is tedious, difficult, and a completely unnecessary waste of effort.  All we needed was the expected value of our random variable, nothing else.  Linearity of expectation turns this into a one or two line problem that can almost be calculated in your head.

Comment: @JMoravitz I *answered* and then deleted my post because although I suspected that Linearity of Expectation applies, I can't **prove it**.  I'm familiar with the hypothesis.  Is there an online **proof** of Linearity of expectation that someone with a semi-cobwebbed undergraduate knowledge of probability can study that will then delineate exactly when the Linearity of expectation can be validly applied?

Comment: @user2661923 linearity of expectation always applies.  The only question is if it is useful.  It is *always* the case that $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$, regardless whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are independent on one another or otherwise.  The only challenge in this problem should be in recognizing that it is in fact useful here and that the random variable describing "The total number of animals who were the favorites of exactly seven people" is equal to the sum of the $23$ random variables "$1$ if the $i$'th animal is the favorite of exactly $7$ people and $0$ otherwise" for each $1\leq i\leq 23$